# How to exclude one subfolder from my RewriteRule Htaccess rules?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite, rewritecond

I have a .htaccess in my root of website that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.pl [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([a-z0-9_-]+)\.mydomain\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?run=places/%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/upload/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/javascript/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?runit=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've installed custom guest book in folder guests and now I would like to disable rules above for this one specific folder. So that when I type:

```
mydomain.pl/guests
```

I would like to go normally to actual folder guests. I understand that I need to somehow disable rules above for guests subfolder, but how do I do this?

Comment: Anyone canm help?

Comment: Any particular reason you can't employ the same method as you use for the folders /images/, /upload/ and /javascript/ ?

Answer (score 4):

A very quick "cheat" is to create a .htaccess in the guests folder with the content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine off
</IfModule>
```

That will turn off rewrite for the folder in question (and any subfolders)